# Parsing in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to do xml parsing of finding the "Humidity", "Current Temperature" and the "Icon" of the temperature(a SUN) in my android application.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: you should post a chuck of your xml file so we can figure out what "Humidity", "Current Temperature" and "Icon" are (elements, attribute names?)

Comment: Humidity, Current Temperature and the Icon are the three things which I have to dispaly in my Application when the "Current Location" gets found by Calling a Web Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really related to Android platform, since Android supports standard JAXP (Java API for XML Processing). So you can use both SAX or DOM to process your file.

For comprehensive information about XML processing in Java you could take a look at [this book](http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/).

For a quicker Java XML processing tutorial [here you have an example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/index.html) (there are thousands).